# no output generated from this simple python code?

Tags: python

Do I miss anything here? Why does this code not outputting data to the file I opened? Any ideas?

The following is the essential part of the entire code that has passed the complier without errors, but not outputting data to the file.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

#Basic imports
import sys
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime,date,time
import numpy as np

#Create Bridge objects
try:
    bridge_1 = Bridge()

outfile = open("prototype.csv", "a")


# Initialize all sensors and discard the readings
    lc1_ini = bridge_1.getBridgeValue(0) * 2674.0 - 210.7

    sleep(1)

    lc1 = bridge_1.getBridgeValue(0) * 2674.0 - 210.7



# create empty array to store the converted digital data
    readings_lc1 = np.empty([])

    avg_lc1 = np.empty([])

    max_samples = 3

    readings_lc1  = np.append(readings_lc1 , lc1 )

    if len(readings_lc1) == max_samples:        
     avg_lc1  = np.mean(readings_lc1[1:])


    #Write the data to the text file

    outfile.write(str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + "," + str(round(lc1,2)) + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

Comment: well you don't show us your definitions for `bridge_1` or `outfile`, so we probably won't be able to tell you...

Comment: What do you mean? No output to the console, or no output to the `outfile`? Where do you define/open `outfile`?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to best formulate your question to get an effective answer.  Most notably, how to provide a MVCE.

Comment: Please see modified post. Thanks.

Comment: you don't seem to have the corresponding `except` statement for your `try`; that will produce a syntax error

Comment: I removed the except statement from the post, because the entire code is too lengthy.

Comment: Please reduce your original code to the shortest **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See [mcve] and [ask].